# Canadian FHSA to RRSP after 15 years

Tags: canada, rrsp, canada-revenue-agency

I am a Canadian Resident Tax Payer.

- I regularly max out on my RRSP contribution room.
- I never owned a home, I have been renting because I move around a lot because of work (Canada & USA).
- I am interested in opening the new FHSA account that would help reduce my taxable income or I could use it to buy my first home if I find a suitable property.

**My question**

*If I open the FHSA account and I am not able to buy a house in the 15 years time period. When I convert the FHSA to an RRSP will there be any penalty involved because I am regularly maxing out my RRSP contributions and there will not be any room left to accommodate any new contributions.*

Can someone comment on how this works.

Comment: I would not count on the rules regarding transfers between a FHSA to a RRSP being the same 15 years from now. Note you also lose out on the biggest benefit : qualifying withdrawals do not count as income. Once transferred to a RRSP any money coming out is counted as income. Might be better off just using a TFSA depending on tax bracket in retirement.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a no-brainer to open an FHSA. You’ll get a tax deduction for the amount contributed.  $8K max per year, up to a max of $40,000, but only if you opened the FHSA in 2023. If you didn't open the FHSA in 2023, your max contribution is now reduced to $32000 ($8000 x 4). And you have 15 years to decide, use the money to purchase a house (tax free), or transfer it to your RRSP (and pay later as income). The transfer to your RRSP does not impact your RRSP contribution room.

Comment: The lifetime contribution room is still $40k, you just can't carryforward the annual $8k until you actually open an account.  https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/first-home-savings-account/contributing-your-fhsa.html

Comment: Yes Brian, you are correct. The lifetime contribution room for a FHSA is $40K. Thanks for catching that!